# How to check whether email or mobile is registered or not in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to implement sign up with two activities with the help of firebase, first sign up activity contains email mobile and password, and in this activity i want to check whether the entered email ID or mobile is registered or not, if it does not then move the data(i.e. email, mobile no. and password) to next activity where final registration will happen. The two methods which are present in the code i.e. **userMobileExists() and userEmailExists()** to check the email and mobile. But the problem is these are asynchronous so when I go to next activity then the Toast appear that email is already registered.
I am returning valid, if all the valid are true then it goes to next activity , I debugged it and it returns valid before going inside the method. It is because of asynchronous code, Please suggest something how it can be achieved on the first activity only. Or tell if I should provide the whole code.

```
 public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;

    private Firebase mRef = new Firebase("https://abcdef.firebaseio.com/");
    private User user;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    boolean valid = true;
    String email;
    String mobile;
    String password;

    @Bind(R.id.input_email)
    EditText _emailText;
    @Bind(R.id.input_mobile)
    EditText _mobileText;
    @Bind(R.id.input_password)
    EditText _passwordText;
    @Bind(R.id.btn_next)
    Button _signupButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        //For Full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //Back button initialization
        Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_signup);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent in = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // mRef = Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);


        _signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signup();
            }
        });

    }

    protected void setUpUser() {

        user.setPhoneNumber(_mobileText.getText().toString());
        user.setEmail(_emailText.getText().toString());
        user.setPassword(_passwordText.getText().toString());
    }

    //private void

    public void signup() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Signup");
        //showProgressDialog();
        if (validate() && userEmailExist() && userMobileExist()) {
            onSignupSuccess();

        } else {
            onSignupFailed();
            return;
        }

        //_signupButton.setEnabled(false);

        email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        mobile = _mobileText.getText().toString();
        password = _passwordText.getText().toString();


        // TODO: Implement your own signup logic here.


    }


    public void onSignupSuccess() {
        //_signupButton.setEnabled(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "NEXT        BUTTTON");
        //hideProgressDialog();
        Intent in = new Intent(this, SignupActivity2.class);
        in.putExtra("Email", _emailText.getText().toString());
        in.putExtra("Mobile", _mobileText.getText().toString());
        startActivity(in);

        /*setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
        finish();*/
    }

    public void onSignupFailed() {

        // hideProgressDialog();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SignUp failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {


        email = _emailText.getText().toString();
        mobile = _mobileText.getText().toString();
        password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _emailText.setError(null);
        }

        if (mobile.isEmpty() || mobile.length() != 10) {
            _mobileText.setError("Enter Valid Mobile Number");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _mobileText.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }
        return valid;
    }

    public boolean userEmailExist() {
        //private Firebase mRef = new Firebase("https://.firebaseio.com/users/");
        mRef.child("users").orderByChild("email").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue()== _emailText.getText().toString()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Email already exist. Please choose a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    _emailText.setError("Email already exist. Please choose a different one");
                    valid = false;
                } else {
                    email = _emailText.getText().toString();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
        return valid;
    }

    public boolean userMobileExist() {
        mRef.child("users").
                orderByChild("cellPhone").equalTo(_mobileText.getText().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    _mobileText.setError("Mobile Number already exist");
                    valid = false;
                } else {
                    mobile = _mobileText.getText().toString();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });


        return valid;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Disable going back to the MainActivity
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    public void showProgressDialog(){
        if(mProgressDialog == null){
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("loading");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    public void hideProgressDialog(){

        if(mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grasp the concept of callbacks. You cannot return a variable that's assigned asynchronously.

As a quick solution to your problem, start with an interface

```
public interface OnUserActionListener {
    void onExists(Boolean exists);
}
```

Then, make your methods be void and accept a parameter

```
public void userEmailExist(final String email, final OnUserActionListener listener) {
    mRef.child("users")
        .orderByChild("email")
        .equalTo(email)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        listener.onExists( dataSnapshot.exists() );
    }

    ... 

    // no return statement 
}
```

Then, when you call that method, you can pass in the string value you want to search for, and implement your interface.

So replace this synchronous code

```
validate() && userEmailExist()
```

With the async version

```
if (validate()) { // This is synchonous
    final String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
    final String mobile = _mobileText.getText().toString(); 

    // This is asynchronous
    userEmailExist(email, new OnUserActionListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onExists(Boolean exists) {
            if (exists) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Email already exist. Please choose a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                _emailText.setError("Email already exist. Please choose a different one");
                onSignupFailed();
            } else {
                onSignupSuccess();
            }
        } 

    });
```

However you choose to define that interface is up to you

And again, worth repeating, don't assign a field `valid` within your callbacks. Try your best to implement all logic requiring a value to the callback itself

---

You can also implement the entire interface on the class, which is what I would recommend in this scenario as a SignUpActivity because you want to listen for user event actions such as success or error

Just an example using the method names you already have

```
public interface OnUserActionListener {
    // Combine the email and phone into one action
    void onUserExists(User user, Boolean exists); 
    void onSignupSuccess(User user);
    void onSignupFailed(String reason);
}
```

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
   implements OnUserActionListner {   // Implement this interface

   // Define the needed methods
   @Override
   public void onUserExists(User user, Boolean exists) {
       if (exists) {
           onSignupFailed("User " + user + " already exists");
       } else {
           onSignupSuccess(user);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onSignupSuccess(User user) {
       // Do something
   }

   @Override
   public void onSignupFailed(String reason) {
       Toast.makeText(this, reason, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
       ... 
   }
```

etc. etc.

Then, that other method call simply becomes.

```
if (validate()) { // This is synchonous
    final String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
    final String mobile = _mobileText.getText().toString(); 

    // This is asynchronous & you defined the Activity as the interface
    userEmailExist(email, SignupActivity.this);
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused, what is a userExists, and where to call it, secondly, onExists is a boolean defined in the interface, then a boolean should be written in that.

Comment: I meant userEmailExist, and the interface should be a void method

Comment: hey i just edited it, can you tell exactly where to insert the code, did all the interface and implemented method, just getting confused how to check the condition means where to insert the code.

Comment: You need to rewrite `if (validate() && userEmailExist() && userMobileExist())` entirely... You should really check if a `User` object exists and is valid. Check the email and/or the phone number *together* rather than *separate*

Comment: I have updated my answer with how I would write it, but it is a very broad answer, and it takes a some time to fully grasp what is happening...

Comment: In the first approach we are just checking for email, what about mobile, if email doesn't exist then it will call the onSiignUpSuccess but it should also check for unique mobile as well Then it should call for onSignUpSuccess or something. or what I was thinking was in else condition call the userMobileExists and inside of that else call onSignUpSuccess.

Comment: I only did emails because the same pattern applies. You can chain the requests after one another, yes.  Or you could rewrite your Firebase query to check both at once, but that's best asked in a new post

Comment: i chained it but mobile no. is not getting validated, i m inserting the mobile no. in the form of this : 1234567890, but in firebase it shows like this (123) 456-8970.Can you explain how to check both at once, if you can please explain in this post only as i asked for both.

Comment: I understand you asked for both. However, I am not aware how Firebase internally stores phone numbers. Perhaps your Android app's `getText().toString()` has formatted the data that way when you inserted the string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not satisfied with the accepted answer because when I used it in my project it still failed. After trying many thing I write my own code ... and it is working. If you want check whether user is already registered or not you can try the following code.

```
 private void isUserAlreadySignUp(String phone){
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("authUser");
        // after getting reference of child, checked orderbykey so we get if phone is key we can get ref in dataSnapshot...
        databaseReference.child( "userPhone" ).orderByKey().equalTo( phone ).addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Boolean isExists = dataSnapshot.exists();
                if (isExists)
                    showToast(  "This number is alredy Registerd..!!" );
                else
                {
                    // if mobile is not registered you can go ahead...
                     // You can write your further code here or call methods...
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                showToast("Error :" + databaseError);
                wSignUpProgressBar.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            }
        } );
    }

// For Toast msg...
private  void  showToast(String s){ Toast.makeText( getActivity(), s , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); }
```

To register a users mobile number on the database after authenticating the user, you can call this method.

```
 // Register User on the database --------------------------
    private  void registerUserOnDatabase( String userPhone){
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("authUser").child("userPhone");
        userRef.child( userPhone ).setValue( userPhone );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void checkUserCnicPhoneExists() {
    
    firebaseDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            boolean cnicExists = false;
            boolean phoneExists = false;

            if(snapshot.exists())
            {
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    if (user.getCnicNo().equals(cnic.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        cnicExists = true;
                    }
                    if (user.getPhoneNo().equals(phone.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        phoneExists = true;
                    }
                }

                if (cnicExists || phoneExists)
                {
                    if (cnicExists && phoneExists)
                    {
                        // Phone number already exists
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Phone number already exists. Please choose a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        phone.setError("Phone number already exists. Please choose a different one");

                        // CNIC number already exists
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CNIC number already exists. Please choose a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        cnic.setError("CNIC number already exists. Please choose a different one");
                    }
                    else if (phoneExists)
                    {
                        // Phone number already exists
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Phone number already exists. Please choose a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        phone.setError("Phone number already exists. Please choose a different one");
                    }
                    else if (cnicExists)
                    {
                        // CNIC number already exists
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CNIC number already exists. Please choose a different one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        cnic.setError("CNIC number already exists. Please choose a different one");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // CNIC number does not exist
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "create acc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).